# Joomla - create hidden test page

Tags: joomla, joomla1.6

I'm a newbie to Joomla. Is there any way to create a test page which is not visible to all but for those which are logged in? I have installed Joomla 1.6

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to switch the access permission from "public" to "registerd" in the article editing form.

Comment: Bud do I need to add it to the menu to have it accessible? Or just use alias as URI?

Comment: you should add it to the menu, but you can make the menu item for registered users only too. or you create a hidden menu you add the test page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sample menu through 'menu manger' and assign an article to the that menu item.This menu item will not be visible to the users until you provide some link to main menu or some other visible menu managers.Now, You can access that page by using the following url "http://localhost/practise/index.php/[name of the menu]"